# Is gcc a table based compiler?

Tags: gcc

AFAIK LR parsers are all writen by YACC alike tools, which are table based.

While LL parsers can be writen manually by recursive top-down descendent algorithm.

Which is the case for gcc, or is it using an entirely different solution?

Answer (score 1):

For C gcc used to use [bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), which is a yacc rewrite. It seems to have a recursive descent parser today.

Comment: Google seems not show up the recursive descent parser of gcc's c front end,do you have any reference for that?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a specific policy for front-end implementation in gcc, front-end authors choose the approach they consider best for the language they are implementing. The C++ front-end uses a hand written recursive descent parser.

Comment: `The C++ front-end uses a hand written recursive descent parser`,could you provide a link to the related source or article?

Comment: I actually read it on the gcc mailing list, but it is also mentioned in the [Wikipedia page for gcc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection).